# in Flex, how to add child as first child?

Tags: apache-flex

I am adding child as:

containerComponent.addChild(newComponent);

But, it adds it as last child. How can I add newComponent as first child of containerComponent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use addChildAt instead of addChild with the index parameter set to 0:

```
containerComponent.addChildAt(newComponent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

containerComponent.addChildAt(0, newComponent);

Comment: containerComponent.addChildAt(newComponent, 0);

Comment: Ok i got the params back to front, i think code hinting would have shown what is needed, i think its harsh to be marked down for that. Great way to promote knowledge sharing....